# Android Magnetic windshield mount

Tags: android, magnetometer

Could you help me, please? I want to mount my Droid in magnetic windshield mount. How could I check programatically that Droid is mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Add an intent-filter with the CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK category.